# How to bind email config from Destination service in SCP Neo to Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sap-business-technology-platform

I want to deploy a spring boot application in SAP Cloud Platform  Neo environment. It has a endpoint `/sendmail` which sends a mail to a particular user when called. For now, I have hard coded the credentials in `application.properties` file and it works. The file looks as follows -

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=...
spring.mail.password=...
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

Now, I want to make use of the destinations service of the SCP platform where I'll define the credentials of the mail account. I want to fetch the credentials from the destination service. So, what needs to go in `application.properties` file ??

I have performed similar operation in SCP - Cloud Foundry but for a different service ( Database ). CF has the VCAP environment variables which can be used to fetch the credentials as follows -

```
spring.datasource.url=${vcap.services.${vcap.services.name}.credentials.url}
```

Is it possible to do the same here in Neo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK to retrieve destinations and their properties. You can find more information [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/10/first-steps-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/).